# Javascript: setTimeout and multiple Prompts

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code that loads a prompt on page launch: "Do you believe..."
Gets an answer.  Returns "I see" Alert no matter what the user inputs, waits for 10,000 milliseconds and then enters a second prompt.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  When I delete the timeout function and everything underneath that, the prompt works just fine but not sure how I can make the rest work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>T-Master, what drink would you like?</title>
</head>

<body>


<script>
window.onload=first();

function first(){
var answer = prompt("Do you believe you have the power to change the world?");

switch(answer){
    default:
    alert("...I see");

setTimeout(function(){
    //do what you need here
}, 
10000);

}

var answer2 = prompt("Master, your drink?");
var text;

switch(answer2){
    case "Gatorade":
    text = "THat's what I thought sire";
    break;

    case "Orange Juice":
    text = "That's a good choice sir";
    break;

    case "Bliss"
    text = "Hmm, a finer choice than what I expected";
    break;

    case "nothing";
    text = "Very well sir";
    break;

    default:
    text = "I'll get on it";
    break;
}
alert(text);
}
</script>






</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why would you use a switch and then not do anything but use the default?

Comment: "waits for 10,000 milliseconds" — No, it doesn't. That isn't what `setTimeout` does.

Comment: "and then enters a second prompt" — Again, obviously.

Comment: @Quentin it's obvious he is new to JavaScript (and likely programming)... maybe throw him a bone

Comment: @Quentin then maybe stay away from people like this if you don't know how to help them, just beat them up.

Comment: @MitchellSimoens — Getting them to explain what the problem actually is is the first stage to helping them.

Comment: @Quentin And if that's what you want to do then great! Just do it in a constructive way.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, I did it bud, thanks for cheering me on

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You have a mix of async and sync programming there. Your `prompt` call is sync but the `setTimeout` is async and will execute after the code that comes after it.

```
window.onload=first();

function first() {
    var answer = prompt("Do you believe you have the power to change the world?");

    switch(answer) {
        default :
            alert("...I see");

            setTimeout(function() {
                //do what you need here
                var answer2 = prompt("Master, your drink?"),
                    text;

                switch(answer2) {
                    case "Gatorade" :
                        text = "That's what I thought sire";
                        break;
                    case "Orange Juice" :
                        text = "That's a good choice sir";
                        break;
                    case "Bliss" :
                        text = "Hmm, a finer choice than what I expected";
                        break;
                    case "nothing" :
                        text = "Very well sir";
                        break;
                    default :
                        text = "I'll get on it";
                        break;
                }

                alert(text);
            }, 10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just going off what the OP first had. the issue isn't that here, the issue is sync vs async.

Comment: yes, he also had some syntax errors that you fixed, you should add in an explanation of those as well :P

Comment: There is tons wrong with the code, would be a lot to tell him of everything. Instead, I focused on the main issue he was having, sync vs async.